# Create pipeline in Azure that runs R script without generalizing the VM

Tags: r, azure, azure-pipelines, virtual-machine

I have an R script that I need to run once every week. I need it to be done using Azure. One option is to use Azure Data Factory and set up a pipline what will run this R script on a VM (Windows).

The problem I'm facing is that I will have to update every now and then both the R script and the R packages the R script is using.

When setting up this pipeline I will have to generalize the VM (correct me if I'm wrong) and doing so I can no longer log into this VM. And if I can't log into this VM I cannot update the R packages.

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate solution where you can use Azure Batch Service and Azure Data Factory to execute R scripts in your pipeline.

For more information, you can refer this blog: [How to execute R Scripts using Azure Batch Services and Azure Data Factory? | by Aditya Kaushal | Medium](https://adityakaushal-59705.medium.com/how-to-execute-r-scripts-using-azure-batch-services-and-azure-data-factory-ebee62aa19d6)

Alternatively, to run R scripts in your VM, you can use below options:

- Custom Script Extension
- Run Command
- Hybrid Runbook Worker
- Serial console

Reference: [Run scripts in an Azure Windows VM - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-scripts-in-vm)

Comment: But using Azure Batch Service don't you need generalized image, i.e. image of generalized VM? After you generalize the VM you cannot log into the VM (remote desktop as an example) if you need to update/install pacakges on the VM, right?

Comment: In the batch service, you can create the node VMs with generalized VMs. But you can log in to these VMs (nodes) using RDP. These node VMs are not generalized